# smoothScrollToPosition not working in recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, android-xml

I created custom LinearLayoutManager class.My goal is to smoothScrollToPosition with animation.Here is a my code:

```
public class LinearLayoutManagerWithSmoothScroller extends LinearLayoutManager {
private static final float MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH = 100f;

public LinearLayoutManagerWithSmoothScroller(Context context) {
    super(context, VERTICAL, false);
}
@Override
public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state,
                                   int position) {
    RecyclerView.SmoothScroller smoothScroller = new TopSnappedSmoothScroller(recyclerView.getContext());
    smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
    startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
}

private class TopSnappedSmoothScroller extends LinearSmoothScroller {
    public TopSnappedSmoothScroller(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    @Override
    public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
        return LinearLayoutManagerWithSmoothScroller.this
                .computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition);
    }

    @Override
    protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel
            (DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
        return MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH/displayMetrics.densityDpi;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getVerticalSnapPreference() {
        return SNAP_TO_START;
    }
}
```

}

Also,I created custom LayoutAnimation in RecyclerView.Here is a xml code

```
<layoutAnimation
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:animation="@anim/item_animation_from_bottom"
android:delay="15%"
android:animationOrder="normal"
/>
```

And here is my java code.

```
        leaderBoardAdapter = new SPGamificationLeaderBoardAdapter(response.list, getContext());
    leaderBoardRecyclerView.setAdapter(leaderBoardAdapter);
    leaderBoardRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    leaderBoardRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

    LayoutAnimationController controller =
            AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.layout_animation_from_bottom);
    leaderBoardRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(smoothScroller);

    leaderBoardRecyclerView.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
    leaderBoardRecyclerView.scheduleLayoutAnimation();
    leaderBoardRecyclerView.post(() -> leaderBoardRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(getPosition(response)));
```

My problem is that, both options(smoothScrollToPosition and LayoutAnimation) does not working same time.I removed smoothScrollToPosition  and layout animation worked ,and removed smoothScrollToPosition - layout animation has worked.
Is any way to use both functions same time? what's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  `scrollToPosition(itemNo)` for achieving your goal.

Like below:

```
recyclerview.scrollToPosition(20);
```

Using `smoothScrollToPosition` , items are scroll very fast thats why animation is not worked.